# how to make two UILabel side by side in iOS Programatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, xamarin, xamarin.ios, uilabel

I want to show two UILabel side by side programatically as show in the Image below.
[image]

As in the Image show the first Label is short value but it value is dyanmic and the second UILabel is more then two line as show in the Image. But the Second Label is set to Right side of the first UILabel.

Is there any way to do this in programatically way..

I try lot of thing to do this but nothing is help to me.

Any help be Appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this：

```
UILabel *label1 = [[UILabel alloc]init];
[self.view addSubview:label1];
label1.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
label1.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:15];
label1.text = @"ABC";
// this is the way
[label1 setContentHuggingPriority:UILayoutPriorityDefaultHigh forAxis:UILayoutConstraintAxisHorizontal];

UILabel *label2 = [[UILabel alloc]init];
[self.view addSubview:label2];
label2.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:15];
label2.text = @"label2label2label2label2label2label2label2label2label2label2label2";
label2.backgroundColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
label2.numberOfLines = 0;

[label1 mas_makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
    make.left.mas_equalTo(0);
    make.top.mas_equalTo(400);
    make.height.mas_equalTo(18);
}];

[label2 mas_makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
    make.left.mas_equalTo(label1.mas_right);
    make.top.mas_equalTo(label1);
    make.right.mas_offset(0);
}];
```

[image: result]

Comment: Is there any way to do this in Xamarin ios ??

Comment: can you tell me which constraint you have used ??